How to order placeholder elements in Google Slides for usage in Google Apps Script
EDIT: Final solution has been added as answer but I marked Tanaike's answer as solution as he pointed me towards the right direction.
I'm setting up a Google AppScript to automate a bit of reporting.
I'm retrieving some data and then want to create slides as needed to report on all the data.
The presentation I'm using as template has different 3-columns lay-outs with subheader placeholders for the column titles and body placeholders for the column text.
Let's assume the slide layouts are similar to the drawing below.

Using alt text for those fields I was able to somewhat discover the lay-out of the slides.
function getPlaceholders(layout) {
  layout.getPlaceholders().forEach((e, i) => {
    Logger.log("[%s] %s %s", i, e.getPageElementType(), p.getDescription());
  });
}

Will print something like [0.0] SHAPE Header 1 where Column 1 header is the Alt text I set for that placeholder.

But I'm running into 2 issues:

The order of the placeholder elements doesn't follow the visual order of the slide.
On the first slide the order of the headers and body is 2-0-1
The Lay-outs appear to have some errors by which some fields aren't recognized as placeholders, even though the slide does show the default placeholder text in those fields.
It appears that copying the fields from a previous slide causes this issue and I need to redo all fields manually for each layout.

The script below will add only 2 slides.
The first slide will have the fields filled in



Header 0-2
Header 0-0
Header 0-1




Body 0-2
Body 0-0
Body 0-1



The 2nd slide doesn't contain any text in the fields as the scripts seems to fail to discover them.
function test(g) {
  let styles = [
    "CUSTOM_1",
    "CUSTOM_1_2",
    "CUSTOM_1_2_1",
    "CUSTOM_1_2_1_1"
  ]

  styles.forEach((style, index) => {
    let newslide = g.addSlide(g.getLayout(style))

    Logger.log("[%s] %s", index, style);
    newslide.getPlaceholders().forEach((p, i) => {
        // Won't print alt text as those aren't carried from template layouts to actual slides
        Logger.log("  [%s] %s %s %s", i, p.getPageElementType(), p.getTitle(), p.getDescription());
      });
    
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      newslide.getPlaceholder(SlidesApp.PlaceholderType.SUBTITLE, i).asShape().getText().setText(`Header ${index}-${i}`);
      newslide.getPlaceholder(SlidesApp.PlaceholderType.BODY, i).asShape().getText().setText(`Body ${index}-${i}`);
    }
  });
}

This will report e.g.
10:04:39 AM Info    [0.0] CUSTOM_1
10:04:39 AM Info      [0.0] SHAPE  
10:04:39 AM Info      [1.0] SHAPE  
10:04:39 AM Info      [2.0] SHAPE  
10:04:39 AM Info      [3.0] SHAPE  
10:04:39 AM Info      [4.0] SHAPE  
10:04:39 AM Info      [5.0] SHAPE  
10:04:39 AM Info      [6.0] SHAPE  
10:04:40 AM Info    [1.0] CUSTOM_1_2
10:04:40 AM Info      [0.0] SHAPE  
10:04:40 AM Info      [1.0] SHAPE  
10:04:40 AM Info      [2.0] SHAPE  
10:04:40 AM Info      [3.0] SHAPE  
10:04:40 AM Info      [4.0] SHAPE  
10:04:40 AM Info      [5.0] SHAPE  
10:04:40 AM Info      [6.0] SHAPE  
10:04:40 AM Error   
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'asShape')
(anonymous) @ App.gs:115
test    @ App.gs:106
main    @ App.gs:132

It looks like the placeholders on the 2nd slide aren't recognized as being of type SlidesApp.PlaceholderType.SUBTITLE.

So I modified the for loop as follows:
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  newslide.getPlaceholders()[2*i].asShape().getText().setText(`Header ${index}-${i}`);
  newslide.getPlaceholders()[2*i+1].asShape().getText().setText(`Body ${index}-${i}`);
}

This, however, still doesn't result in nice slides as the order of the elements still isn't logical.
Slide 1



Header 0-2
Header 0-0
Header 0-1




Body 0-2
Body 0-0
Body 0-1



Slide 2



Body 1-0
Header 1-1
Header 1-0




Header 1-2
Body 1-2
Click to add text



Slide 3



Header 2-1
Header 2-0
Body 2-0




Click to add text
Header 2-2
Body 2-2



Slide 4



Header 3-1
Header 3-0
Body 3-0




Click to add text
Header 3-2
Body 3-2




What I want to achieve is to be able to programmatically fill these slides in a logical order.
I.e. (in pseudocode)
let index = 0;
let slide;

report.forEach((r) => {
  if (index == 0) { slide = addSlide(layout_x) };

  slide.placeholder(type=subhead)[index].setText(r.title);
  slide.placeholder(type=body)[index].setText(r.content);

  index = (index + 1) % 3;
});

TL;DR;
How can I set up my template for the presentation so that I get a consistent and logical order of placeholder elements?

I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Your showing 4 tables from "Slide 1" to "Slide 4" are existing in 1st to 4th page in your Google Slide? And, this is the input situation? If my understanding is correct, can I ask you about the details of a consistent and logical order of placeholder elements? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

@Tanaike The 4 tables are a representation of the 4 slides created by the script. I've edited my post to add a drawing which may help you visualize what the tables represent.
I'm looking for a way to be able to programmatically say: object 1 from report, place title in subhead at top-left and text in body at top-right, while object 2 goes in the middle and object 3 at the right. For obj4 a new slide is created and content goes in the left column, etc.

Thank you for replying. From your reply and updated question, I thought of an approach for resolving your issue. In your situation, how about managing them using the title and/or the description of each shape in the layout? For example, set a title of "subhead1" to the top left of "Slide Layout 1(CUSTOM_1)". By this, you can search the shape of "subhead1" using a script. In my case, I use the title and description for managing the images on Google Slides. If this was not included in your expected direction, I apologize.

I have tried this using the Alt text description in the Layout (Template Editor), but those aren't copied to the slide once a slide is created based on that slide. Is there a different property I can use?

Thank you for replying. About I have tried this using the Alt text description in the Layout (Template Editor), but those aren't copied to the slide once a slide is created based on that slide., can you provide the sample Slides for correctly replicating it?

@Tanaike I have added some screenshots. There you can see the subtitle placeholder and the Alt text. These are defined in the Slide Layout (Slide > Edit theme). The alt text can be retrieved via Presentation.getLayouts()[i].getPlaceholders()[i].getDescription();
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation#getLayouts() /
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/layout#getplaceholders /
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/page-element#getDescription()

Thank you for replying. From your reply, I would like to prepare a sample Google Slide of your situation and test it.

As another approach instead of the title and description, I proposed using the object ID as an answer. Please confirm it. If this was not also your expected approach, I apologize again.

As another approach instead of the title and description, I would like to propose using the object ID of the objects in the layout. When a layout is set to a slide, the object ID of the layout can be seen as the value of parentObjectId. When the objects (for example, their shape.) are retrieved from a layout, the object ID, title, and description can be retrieved. Using them, each object ID corresponding to each title can be obtained. By this, even when the layout is set to a slide, the origins of the inserted objects can be known using the parentObjectId. When this is reflected in a simple sample script, it becomes as follows.
1. Sample layout
Please prepare the following custom layout. And, set the title of each shape as "subtitle1", "body1", "subtitle2", "body2".

2. Set layout
Please set the created custom layout to the 1st page of the Google Slides. It's as follows.

3. Sample script
In order to correctly insert the texts to each placeholder, the following sample script is used. Please set the custom layout name to layoutName. And, please set the title and the inserted text as the key and value, respectively.
In this sample, the texts of "sample title 1", "sample body 1", "sample title 2", "sample body 2" are inserted into the placeholders of "subtitle1", "body1", "subtitle2", "body2", respectively.
function myFunction() {
  // Please set your custom layout name.
  const layoutName = "CUSTOM";

  // Please set the title and the inserted text as the key and value, respectively.
  const object = {
    subtitle1: "sample title 1",
    body1: "sample body 1",
    subtitle2: "sample title 2",
    body2: "sample body 2",
  };

  // Create an object including the parent object ID and the inserting text.
  const s = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  const layout = s.getLayouts().find(e => e.getLayoutName() == layoutName);
  const newObject = layout.getPageElements().reduce((o, e) => (o[e.getObjectId()] = object[e.getTitle()] || "", o), {});

  // Insert the texts to each object of the placeholder.
  const slide = s.getSlides()[0]; // As a sample, 1st page is used.
  slide.getShapes().forEach(s => {
    const parentObjectId = s.getParentPlaceholder().getObjectId();
    if (newObject[parentObjectId]) {
      s.getText().setText(newObject[parentObjectId]);
    }
  });
}

4. Testing
When this script is run to the above input situation, the following result is obtained.

Note:

This is a simple sample script for explaining my approach. So, please modify this to your actual situation.

In this sample, in order to easily manage, I used the object ID and title of placehoder. Byt, if you have already known the object IDs of all placeholders, I think that you can directly create object in the above script. In that case, const newObject = ,,, is not required to be used.


Reference:

getParentPlaceholder() of Class Shape


Thank you for your help! I'll try it soon.
Quick question: where do I set the element's title. Is it under the Advanced Options under Alt text?

@BlueCacti Thank you for replying. About Quick question: where do I set the element's title. Is it under the Advanced Options under Alt text?, yes. You can set the title of the shape from "Advance options" in "Alt Text" on "Format options".

Awesome! Made a few changes (will post a redacted version of it as an Answer as well) and got it to work

This is a redacted copy of the function I eventually ended up with.
Thanks again to @Tanaike for pointing me in the right direction.
I could probably store references to the TextRange objects instead of the Placeholder objects in the reduce() function to avoid duplicating .asShape().getText().
/**
 * Create the report slides
 * @param {Google} google Google instance
 * @param {Report} report Report instance
 */
function createReportSlides(google, report, project) {
  let styles = [
    "CUSTOM_1",       // layout 0
    "CUSTOM_1_2",     // layout 1
    "CUSTOM_1_2_1",   // layout 2
    "CUSTOM_1_2_1_1", // layout 3
  ]
  let iCounter = 0; // Item counter
  let curTitle = ""; // Current title

  // Uses global variable for list of topics ('title': str, 'items': [])
  TOPICS.forEach((t, i) => {
    let title = t.title;
    let slide;

    if (title != curTitle) {
      /**
       * @todo Add topic overview slide. Copy/move the correct slide or add?
       */
      curTitle = title;
      iCounter = 0;
      let objects = {};
    }

    t.items.forEach((item) => {
        let summaries = report.getItemSummary(project, title, item);

        if (summaries.length > 0) {
          if(iCounter == 0) {
            slide = google.addSlide(google.getLayout(styles[i]));
            objects = slide.getPlaceholders().reduce((o, e) => (
              // Store reference to placeholders based on Alt Title
              // Alt Title is Header_x or Body_x or empty
              o[e.asShape().getParentPlaceholder().getTitle() || "_"] = e, o), {}
            );
          }

          objects[`Header_${lCounter}`].asShape().getText().setText(item);
          objects[`Body_${lCounter}`].asShape().getText().setText(summaries.join("\v")); // \v = vertical tab (same as shift+return)

          iCounter = (iCounter+1)%3;
        }
    });
  });
}

